# is it okay to say "Don't dangle the cable on the floor like that, you may trip over it"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

> [dangle](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dangle?q=dangle) [intransitive, transitive] to hang or move freely; to hold
>   something so that it hangs or moves freely
>
> +adv./prep. Gold charms dangled from her bracelet.
>
> A single light bulb dangled from the ceiling.
>
> He sat on the edge with his legs dangling over the side.
>
> dangle something + adv./prep. She dangled her car keys nervously as
>   she spoke.
>
> He dangled his legs over the edge of the bridge.

---

A child is holding a cable like this

[image]

is it okay to say "**Don't dangle the cable on the floor like that, you may trip over it**"?

**Note:** the cable touched the floor

Comment: I think you mean *trip*.  That would make sense.  Children are hopefully not stripping over anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's touching the floor, the best verb is probably *trail.* https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trail

"Don't let the cable trail on the floor."

Comment: One extra question, how would we ask the child to keep it neatly? Fro example, "Please roll it into a ball", "Please keep it off the floor", or "Please coil it into a loop", etc

Comment: "Please coil it up." ( A coil is made up of many loops.) If it's an electrical cable, I don't think you would roll it into a ball..

Answer (score 0):

First, "dangle" has the sense of being *unsupported* on the bottom. Your illustration doesn't make clear if the end is touching the floor, but your comment clarified it, so the cable is *not* dangling,

Comment: The cable touched the floor